# Can I convert a existing functor to another functor in C++?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++03

I have a vector of `glm::vec3`, as I need to do a search to find the first `vec3` in the vector whose norm is greater than some value(assuming vector is sorted).

I don't have C++11, so I hope to use existing functors available in standard library. Since I need to do a compare, `std::greater_equal` came in my mind. So my first try is this.

```
std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std:: greater_equal<glm::vec3>());
```

It doesn't compile since `find_if` requires unary but `greater_equal` requires two arguments. So second trial is

```
std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind2nd(std::greater_equal<glm::vec3>, glm::vec3(3.0)))
```

This does work as well coz I found out `glm::vec3` doesn't support compares. Then I checked out that it seems I can use `std::mem_fn` to construct a functor but I don't know how to use it here.

Is it possible to have a functor transform vec3 to float then concate another to do the compare on floats?

I know it's kind of lame but I don't want to write a struct with `operator()` all the time for those things.

Thanks very much.

Comment: I think your best option is to just write the `struct` inside the body of the function (this is allowed) so you don’t need to leave it lying around some namespace. `struct norm_greater_than { float valve; operator()(glm::vec3 vec) { ... }}; std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), norm_greater_than{3.0});`

Comment: Local structs cannot be used as template arguments prior to c++11.

Comment: Oh, huh. I didn’t realize that. I haven’t used c++03 in a while.

Comment: “it seems I can use `std::mem_fn`”  No, you can't because [it is C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn).

Comment: You probably want to binary search (std::upper_bound).

Comment: "I don't want to write a struct with operator() all the time for those things." The solution to this problem is C++11. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's 7 years past C++11, are you certain you can't use it?

Comment: Boost.Phoenix? -

Comment: Yes, our project is not migrated to c++11 yet.

Comment: You could start by providing your own comparison operator to vec3, since it doesn't need to be a member. After that you should be able to use the bind2nd solution, or if you have access to C++03 you may probably access to ``bind``?